# cannot call the Body property for "HTMLFile" object in vbscript

Tags: html, vbscript, com

I have a VBSCript File that uses the MSXML2 library to get a response from a website; i'm trying to write that response to an HTMLFile object's body's innerHTML; although the object itself is declared with no issues whatsoever, VBS returns an "OBJECT REQUIRED ['OBJECT']" Error when I try to access the body property.

Here's the code I have so far.

```
const URL = "https://mywebsite.aspx"
Dim o,user,pass,html 
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
o.open "GET", URL , False
o.send 
    'Error occurs here:
html = CreateObject("htmlFile")
html.body.innerHTML= o.responseText
```

When I run this script in a VBA IDE (specifically, as a module in an Excel spreadsheet with all relevant libraries included), it works fine, but returns an error when I run it as a .vbs file. What steps can I take to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize DOM first:

```vb
Set document = CreateObject("htmlfile")
document.write "<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><div>content</div></body></html>"
MsgBox document.body.innerHTML
```

Or

```vb
Set document = CreateObject("htmlfile")
document.open
document.close
document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><div>content</div></body></html>"
MsgBox document.body.innerHTML
```

Note, that `<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><div>content</div></body></html>` just an example, you may use even empty string.

Comment: can one use `<html>` instead of `<document>` ?

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional, that should be `<html>` actually, I fixed the code.